# Android how to center vertically text when I set a background to the textView

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview, alignment

I need to center the TextView in the center of the purple background [image]

This is the XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="somePurplePNG"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Any ideas?
thanks
PS: I can't create a layout that wraps the textview and defines a background.

Comment: android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change **Gravity** of your text view like this

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

or

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved using

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TextView  as this way

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    aandroid:background="@drawable/somePurplePNG"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can align text in a text view programmatically in your java class

```
TextView YourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewid);
//This will align text in both horizontal and Vertical of its container
YourTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

//Place object in the vertical center of its container
YourTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

//Place object in the vertical center of its container
YourTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```